# How to await a fetch function in a function?

Tags: javascript, async-await, fetch

Below is my code

```
export const redirectDomain: any = (lang, ctx, res) => {
    let redirectString;

    const getData = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await fetch('https://www.example.com');
            const data= await response.json();

            return data;
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('[ERROR]');
        }
    };

    const data = getData();
    const redirectUrl = data.split(',');

    return redirectUrl;
};
```

Why the output will show error

> Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

Comment: You have to `const data = await getData()`... though I would expect the error to be something more like `data.split is not a function`

Comment: don't you have to await `getData()` as it is async?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts The error is correct though, evaluating `(undefined).a()` in my console gives `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'a' of undefined`

Comment: @DevanshJ what you should be evaluating is `const data = new Promise(() => {}); data.split()`.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Oh yeah my bad xD You are correct it says "Uncaught TypeError: data.split is not a function"

Answer (score 2):

Things outside the `async` function won't wait for the promise to get resolved. And hence `data` is still `undefined` when you `split` it. So here's one of the solutions...

```
export const redirectDomain: any = async (lang, ctx, res) => {
    let redirectString;

    const getData = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await fetch('https://www.example.com');
            const data = await response.json();

            return data;
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('[ERROR]');
        }
    };

    const data = await getData();
    const redirectUrl = data.split(',');

    return redirectUrl;
};
```

Another solution (I would prefer this):

```
export const redirectDomain: any = async (lang, ctx, res) => {
    let redirectString;
    let data;
    try {
        const response = await fetch('https://www.example.com');
        data = await response.json();
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('[ERROR]');
    }

    const redirectUrl = data.split(',');

    return redirectUrl;
};
```

Also if I were to write this piece of code (let me figure out how I would handle the error xD):

```
export const redirectDomain: any = (lang, ctx, resp) =>
    fetch("https://www.example.com")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => Promise.resolve(data.split(",")));
```

The point I wanted to make is sometimes promises look better than async/await.

Answer (score 1):

Simply await `getData`, `redirectDomain` must be `async` to do this

```
-export const redirectDomain: any = (lang, ctx, res) => {
+export const redirectDomain: any = async (lang, ctx, res) => {
    let redirectString;

    const getData = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await fetch('https://www.example.com');
            const data= await response.json();

            return data;
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('[ERROR]');
        }
    };

-   const data = getData();
+   const data = await getData();
    const redirectUrl = data.split(',');

    return redirectUrl;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because you data is undefined

Try `axios` library, alternative to fetch

```
const resp = axios.get('https://www.example.com');
```

return resp.data;